# Does mupdf have a config file that allows for it to be open in full-screen mode?

Tags: command-line-interface, config, mupdf

Every time I open mupdf, my first command is f to get it in full-screen mode. Can that be automated through a config file?

Comment: I do not think so :/ If you want something more customizable, you might try zathura.

Comment: Even worse: `f H`.